# Help! I have corrupted Jpeg files and I want to get them back to normal!

Tags: jpeg, memory-card, data-corruption

Ok, so here's what has happened. I was in the middle of uploading the photos from my Sony memory stick (I used two different sony cameras with the same memory stick) of my vacation, onto my computer, when the computer suddenly froze.

I didn't know what else to do except to shut it down, (memory stick still in the drive..i had heard if I removed it unsafely, it could make the memory stick worse). When I rebooted the computer, the photos had been deleted from the stick (Because stupid me had deleted them automatically after downloading them), and the files transferred to the computer (Most, not all) became corrupt.

I am fairly good at solving most computer issues (but don't know the ins and outs of data or anything), but this has me stumped. When I tried some recovery software to retrieve the deleted photos from the memory stick, OTHERS became corrupted but the ones that were corrupted in the beginning were okay after the recovery.

It is hard to explain, but the closest I can explain it is like this..an original photo on the computer came out clean, and then the recovered one from the memory stick came out corrupted, and vice versa, or they were both corrupted or both okay. What can I do to fix this?? HELP!?? I need some easy to follow directions.

Comment: This is a technical question that isn't necessarily specific to photography. You would be better off asking a group of people that are more technical with computers than they are with cameras. That being said, without spending a lot of money on commercial software or services you've exhausted your options.

Answer (score 1):

Search for image recovery software.  Sandisk used to supply it free with the purchase of some of their CF cards.  Plug your memory stick into the reader, run the recovery software.

https://www.google.com/search?q=image+recovery+software

Just because the files are deleted on the card doesn't mean they're gone.  Unless you've written to the memory stick since then, all your files should be there.  Plus, many others.  Even if you've written new files, most of the files you want should also still be there.  Most storage devices (i.e. CF, SD, memory sticks) rotate through the storage so that "wear" on the card is mostly uniform.